# How to prepare a fragment before I add it to the view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I have an app that initially displays one fragment, when a button is clicked it transitions to the next fragment. However inside the 2nd fragment there's a `ViewPager` that holds images from a URL. It can take some time to process all the images. And it is processing the images as the button is clicked which then slows down the speed the fragment gets set up, which takes a lot of time. I want the fragment to be there and prepared instantly.

I can fetch the images in the mainActivity. I however cannot set them to the `ViewPager` before the fragmentTransaction is committed because the `ViewPager` doesn't exist until the `onCreateView` method occurs in the fragment which is only called when the transaction is committed. Is there any way to have the fragment set up in the activity before I commit the transaction.

So the user can easily switch between the two fragments without having to wait for them to process. Or should I have rather used tabs. The thing is I don't want a tabs bar to appear at the top of the screen. I want the tabs to change when by button is clicked.

Comment: this is a monolithic question. You should probably break up the wall of text into a problem statement and a question or two.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're processing the images in the main thread? I think it would be best if, instead, you just pass the URL to your second fragment and have it use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) to process those images in the background, with placeholders for each image as it's getting loaded.

If you insist on doing the loading in the first fragment, you should just be able to set up and add your second fragment without any images, but have it be hidden. Then, once your loading is complete, you will still have access to your `ViewPager` from your first fragment and can use another transaction to `show` the second fragment when ready.

P.S. it would be easier to read/understand your question if it was laid out more logically and not a huge paragraph.